# Нумерация строк в DataTable как источнике для DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms

Здравствуйте.

Делаю программу - SpreadSheet (аналог Екселя). Нужно пронумеровать строки в DataGridView.

[image: Например так]

Но т.к. хранить данные в контроле - плохая идея, было решено использовать экземпляр DataTable для DataGridView как источник данных (свойство DataSource).

```
private DataTable table;
//.......
table = new DataTable();
DataGridView.DataSource = table;
```

Но если нумерацию столбцов поддерживает как DataGridView, так и DataTable и с этим нет проблем, то нумерацию строк у меня получилось найти только в DataGridView. Нужно сделать обычную нумерацию строк как в Excel (1, 2, 3, ...). Аналогичный код для DataTable я не нашел:

```
rows = DataGridView.RowCount;
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
    DataGridView.Rows[i].HeaderCell.Value = (i + 1).ToString();   // i+1 потому, что нумерация нужна 
}                                              // с еденицы, а не с нуля
```

Действительно ли DataTable не поддерживает нумерацию строк? Если поддерживает, как ее сделать? Если не поддерживает, какой тогда источник данных для DataGridView лучше использовать?

P.S. При использовании DataTable как источника данных, пронумеровать DataGridView напрямую, как в коде выше, уже почему-то нельзя. Хотя без использования DataTable, нумерация строк отлично работает. Ни ошибки, ни предупреждения нет, код попросту ни к чему не приводит, как будто ничего и не нумеровал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В DataTable можно завести отдельную колонку.

Привязать ее к DataGridView и сделать нередактируемой.

Когда добавляется новая запись в DataGridView ты вызываешь событие, которое тбе задаст новый номер.

Когда ты удаляешь строку из DataGridView , ты пробегаешь по всему DataTable и меняешь нумерацию.